# can't push git repository from pc to github

Tags: git, github

when i use command bellow to push ...

```
$ git push -u multi_thread2 HEAD
```

after several minutes i see error below:

```
error: src refspec HEAD does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mohamadreza/multi.git
```

notice: i am in Iran and by starting internet filtering or censorship of global net in Iran it has been happening to me.

i can't connect to github by through git in pc !!!!!
what should be done to fix it?

Comment: the command should be git push -u origin HEAD  (origin is the remote, multi_thread2 (or HEAD) is the branch)

Comment: The only way to get the error `src refspec HEAD does not match any` is to be on what Git calls an *orphan branch* or *unborn branch*, which typically happens in a new, totally-empty repository. The fix is to make some commit(s) first.